# Windows phone 7 toolkit problems when converting to Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I Have quite a few errors when I converted my WP7 app to WP 8 app.

I am still quite new to this, I can happily code in WP7 but converting it seems to be harder than expected.

How can one keep the following items from the WP 7 toolkit working when I convert the app to WP8?
ToogleSwitch
ListPicker
AutoCompleteBox

I have put it in this link - www.henryedwards.co.uk/windowsphone8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the latest WPToolkit installed (make sure you have the latest nuget and grab it from there) and that you are referencing the correct libraries. I just did the following:

1. Installed the latest nuget from http://www.nuget.org/
2. File -> New Project -> Windows Phone Application
3. Added WPToolkit to this project
4. added the following to my code:

`xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`

(under

and then used:

```
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox></toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
        <toolkit:ListPicker></toolkit:ListPicker>
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch></toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have added that - my resources that I have got installed - www.henryedwards.co.uk/toolkit.png

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I am getting - Error 7 The type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' exists in both 'c:\Users\Henry\SkyDrive\BrightonHoveBusesAppV7.5\Library\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\Microsoft.Phone.dll' C:\Users\Henry\SkyDrive\Brighton&HoveBusesAppV8\obj\Release\PivotPage1.g.cs 53 43 BrightonHoveBuses

Comment: That makes sense - you're including the Toolkit twice :) Remove the 7.5 version and you should be golden.

Comment: Ok, so I removed the 7.5 version and I get the first 6 errors on this screen shot. www.henryedwards.co.uk/windowsphone8.png

Comment: Did you follow my code sample above? You have a configuration error in your project. Start a new project and follow my above steps and see if it works for you.

Comment: awesome! I'd look to make sure that you are really referencing the correct toolkit and then do a text search through your project to make sure that all references to the old one are gone.